# Webdriver sendkeys() not working . Using javascript also failing

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

## Trying to send/set text using webdriver sendkeys() function for text field

### Here is the HTML

```
<table class="gridtable" cellspacing="0" __gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingfocus="true"    gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingblur="true" style="width: 100%;">
<thead>
<colgroup>
<tbody style="">
<tr class="GORM0XEDKD GORM0XEDME" onclick="">
   <td class="GORM0XEDJD GORM0XEDLD GORM0XEDMD GORM0XEDNE">
   <td class="GORM0XEDJD GORM0XEDLD GORM0XEDNE GORM0XEDGE">
       <div style="outline:none;" tabindex="0"></div>
   </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tbody style="display: none;">
<tfoot style="display: none;">
</table>

Xpath for the text field -
EmailTemplateEditorTemplateName=  By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'GORM0XEDJD GORM0XEDLD  GORM0XEDNE GORM0XEDGE')]/div[1]");
```

- Tried following options. But all are failing to send text to  EmailTemplateEditorTemplateName text field

  ```
  1. driver.findElement(DesignerLocators.EmailTemplateEditorTemplateName).sendKeys("yahooo");

  2. this.WaitForElement(DesignerLocators.EmailTemplateEditorTemplateName);
     WebElement tempname = driver.findElement(DesignerLocators.EmailTemplateEditorTemplateName);
     JavascriptExecutor rightexecutor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
     rightexecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','yahoo')", tempname);

  3. WebElement Element=driver.findElement(DesignerLocators.EmailTemplateEditorTemplateName);
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.moveToElement(Element).sendKeys("yahoo").build().perform();

  4. WebElement Element=driver.findElement(DesignerLocators.EmailTemplateEditorTemplateName);
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.moveToElement(Element).click().sendKeys("yahoo").build().perform();

  5. WebElement Element=driver.findElement(DesignerLocators.EmailTemplateEditorTemplateName);
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.moveToElement(Element).click(Element).sendKeys("yahoo").build().perform();
  ```
- click() is working.
- Interestingly getText() is working for the same text field using same xpath.
  String    val=driver.findElement(DesignerLocators.EmailTemplateEditorTemplateName).getText();
- Only sendKeys() is not working. And not throwing any error.
- Please help me to set/send text in my text field.

Comment: PLease share the error or exception you are getting

Comment: sendKeys() executing successfully but text is not setting in text field. So i am not getting any error or exception.

Comment: and in case of using native javascript?

Comment: Yes ..even with using javascript failing to set/send text in text field.

Comment: I don't see any input elements in your HTML. Looks like you are trying to send keys to a div element?

Comment: shri046-  text field highlighting the div element in HTML. As i mentioned same xpath is working fine for getText().

Comment: Still don't get it, text field highlighting the div element? As long as the element is found and visible, `getText()` will always work.

Comment: Shri046- text field highlighting the div element. When i set text field value manually then the div element is ----  <div style="outline:none;" tabindex="0">yahoo</div>

Comment: When performing the same action manually **(not automating, just normally performing the task)**, does the input textfield come up when you click on the cell of the "gridtable" ?

Comment: Subh - When i move cursor on div element in HTML (Firebug) content then textfield get highlighted.

Comment: Manually, Click on the div element and then check with firebug. Does an **input element** come up within the **div element** above?  My guess, the **display attribute is none for the input field**, hence you are not able to use **sendKeys**.

Comment: Subh - There is no input element in div element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct option in Selenium/Webdriver to set the value in "div" tag.

You need to Set the attribute `innerHTML` using `JavascriptExecutor` as below:

```
   this.WaitForElement(DesignerLocators.EmailTemplateEditorTemplateName);
   WebElement tempname = driver.findElement(DesignerLocators.EmailTemplateEditorTemplateName);
   JavascriptExecutor rightexecutor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
   rightexecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('innerHTML','yahoo')", tempname);
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried this:

Since you said that Click works,

```
driver.findElement(DesignerLocators.EmailTemplateEditorTemplateName).click();
driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys("Text");
```

or trying with builder click and activeElement as below

```
builder.moveToElement(Element).click();
driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys("Text");
```

Answer (score 0):

Check and see that latest version on driver(chromeor firefox) is being used as per the browser version. Please do this basic verification first. This mostly resolves the issue.